# On a conjecture about tilting modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

There is the following conjecture on tilting modules (see also [History of an open problem on partial tilting modules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298812/history-of-an-open-problem-on-partial-tilting-modules)):

Given a partial tilting module $T$ over a finite dimensional algebra $A$ (that is $Ext_A^i(T,T)=0$ for all $i \geq 1$ and $pd(T) < \infty$), then $T$ is a tilting module iff $|T|=n$ where $n$ denotes the number of simple $A$-modules and $|T|$ the number of non-isomorphic indecomposable summands of $T$.

The conjecture is true for tilting modules of projective dimension one and thus for all hereditary algebras.

Questions:

> Is this conjecture known for algebras of global dimension 2 (or any finite global dimension)?
>
> Is the conjecture known for tilting modules of projective dimension 2?
>
> Is this conjecture known for representation finite algebras?

Comment: For representation-finite algebras the conjecture is true by (the dual) of Proposition 5.12 in https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(91)90037-8.